# Python Tkinter Entry Values Method Errors

Tags: python, variables, methods, tkinter

The code is intended to write a few things to a line in a text file.

```
from tkinter import *
Tag=0
x="txt.txt"
w=open(x,"w")
root=Tk()
win1=Frame(root)
Label(root,text="Tag").pack()
tagE=Entry(root)
tagE.pack()
def get_it():                    
    Tag=(tagE.get())                                                                       
v=Button(root,text="Submit",command=get_it)
v.pack()
win1.pack()
w.write("%s var=%s"%(Tag,"text"))
w.close()
root.mainloop()
```

The Tag=(tagE.get()) is indented for more spaces than it is. When i run this code i will either get a "AttributError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' or the tag value will equal its original value of 0. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The indentation in your example is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from getting the value of the entry, you have to write the value in the file in the same function:

```
from tkinter import *

filename = "txt.txt"
root=Tk()
Label(root,text="Tag").pack()
tagE=Entry(root)
tagE.pack()

def get_it():
    w=open(filename, "w")
    tag = tagE.get()
    w.write("%s var=%s"%(tag,"text"))
    w.close()

v=Button(root,text="Submit",command=get_it)
v.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Since you don't use the `Frame`  as parent of any of your widgets, you can use the root element directly. As a side note, I recommend you to use lowercase notation for your variables as suggested in the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and try to use clearer names.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how Tkinter works. Your print statement will execute before you have a chance to click the button. You need to put your print statement inside `get_it`.